# How to configure Quartz mbean

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I am trying to configure Quartz(1.8) in my server application (Jboss5.1.x EJB3.0)
I have deleted the old jars from jboss and placed the new ones (ver 1.8) from Quartz website.

I made quartz-service.xml and put it under default\conf

Now if I understood right, I want when I deploy my application at the server to start scheduling my task automatically.

So next is to add a service to the jboss-service.xml.

1. how do I configure Quartz mbean at jboss-service.xml?
2. how do I set it to execute the java code inside my application?

thanks all,

ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/84-jboss-quartz.html). Looks self explanatory.

Comment: I tried. but couldnt annotate @ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar"), and got more errors.. and there is no word about  jboss-service.xml.

Comment: Do you have the quartz jar files in your lib folder? Also do you see Quartz MBean service in your jboss?

Comment: Yes you need to register its the quartz MBean to add it to Jboss. Your other option is to run Quartz standalone. I have changed the tutorial link to a more step by step one. Hopefully that will get you started. Let us know if you get stuck while following the tutorial.

Comment: I have managed to configure the xml, but how Do I trigger a session bean to start when my server will deploy? I dont have main() I am using EJB. thanks

Comment: You want it to start when it gets deployed or do you want to set up a timer in the quartz scheduler for it to kick of at internals?

Comment: I want my scheduler to start when it gets deployed

Comment: You need to add dependency in your quartz-service.xml inside jboss deployement with sth like a : <depends>jboss.j2ee:service=EARDeployment,url='app2.ear'</depends>